# TaskBar not synced with TaskBar folder Windows 10

Tags: windows, windows-10, taskbar, desktop

My Taskbar is not displaying all the shortcuts I have set in Windows 10.  I have a picture below which shows my Taskbar Folder with many shortcuts in it but my taskbar only displaying Chrome (Skype and File Explorer are open).  I have done a lot of trouble shooting but cannot find why this happens.  It started occurring when I moved my desktop from the C-Drive to an external Drive.

[image]

Comment: If you pin one of them again, does it stick?

Comment: It does until I restart the computer

Comment: How did you move your desktop to an external drive? You may have done something incompletely.

Comment: I went to the Desktop folder, right clicked properties, then clicked location and changed the location to a different drive..